# how to assert that an imported value is of a certain type

Tags: typescript

I am importing a value (`f`) from a module and its type (`F`) from another module. How can I assert that `f` is of type `F`?

The below ugliness is what I currently do:

```
import {f} from './some-module.js';
import {F} from './types.d.ts';

const useless: {f: F} = {f};
```

Comment: Do you want to compare the *static* type of `f`  with `F` (I am asking, since it is imported from a `.js` module)? If not sufficient, you usually use a type guard to do some run-time checks.

Comment: @ford04 the _static_ type of `f` as opposed to what other type exactly? Pardon the question, I am new  to typescript.

Comment: By static type I mean the type for `f`, that the compiler is able to automatically infer, even given a `.js` file (e.g. by JSDoc, or other heuristics). Btw: are you using Deno (otherwise you should leave out file extensions)?

Comment: yes, _static_ type, I want the test to be performed at compile type, not runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Assert` helper to compare two types at compile-time:

```
type Assert<Expected, Actual extends Expected> = void

// let's assume, we imported `f` from './some-module.js'
const f = { a: "foo" }

// also assume import from './types.d.ts'
type F = { a: string }
type F2 = { a: number }

type AssertF = Assert<F, typeof f> // OK
type AssertF2 = Assert<F2, typeof f> // error, f not of type F2
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=64&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznCAnYAeAogD0gY2BAEwBpY8BXAQwBsoJN8A7AuKLXfAgPigF4oA3APYBLAgCgxAeklQqEYAHIWFBGQC2EEgHdowtWEEpCUYcCgAzJILVQKUAHQArFmsEEycsTkEM4Z87xQAN62AFxQAETmgoIRUAC%20EtK2qhom%20oZmABbI0MAxYqCQUABigSEU4X5IwgwA5gmF4NAlAEzlYVAM6gBGyI1NxfCIKGV8w8hoJSRFEIIB5tzJAPIA0oPQE6Pt4wiTqG0zzfMWSzLIVkgkAQyCZiezpa1AA)